# Can't see source code, converting PNG to SWF

Tags: png, flash, flashdevelop

So I'm following this tutorial and in the part, "***Getting graphics there***", the guy/girl says to, and I quote, "*We’ll start with what I consider the best one, an swf. Make a new directory in the root of your project folder called assets and save [this nice picture of a leek](http://prototyprally.com/files/2008/12/leek.swf) in there.*"

In the linked webpage there was no copy or *save as...* option when right-clicking, so I googled how to copy swf from websites and it said to view source code, and to do so by hitting CTRL + U on chrome. I did and nothing. So I tried going on the top right corner > Tools > Developer Tools and it gave me the page HTML, but in the code, where the HTML was getting the image from was the webpage link itself, so... help? ^^".

**Maybe I'm suposed to save the link/location to that image and FlashDevelop will get it from there?**

(I can't print screen it because I'll get the white background by doing so when I believe the file is the leek only, with no background.)

The problem can also be solved in another way since getting this particular leek is not important, I do have an image I made in photoshop and I could use it aswell, although it's PNG and not SWF as he says in the tutorial... :P

Are there any online png to swf converters? How can it be done properly?

I just need help getting an swf image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SWF file is a compiled Adobe Flash "movie." It's not really an image. Flash movies can be interactive, dynamic, static, etc., much like a Java applet. For this reason, there is no way to "convert" a PNG file to an SWF file. If you had Adobe Flash, you could create an SWF yourself, but chances are you do not.

In the case of your leek, it appears to be just a simple static image embedded in the SWF. The reason you didn't see "copy" or "save as" when right-clicking was that Adobe Flash player has its own context menu. Ctrl-U didn't work either because Flash player traps keystrokes. If you want to save it, you can use your browser's file menu. That would be the easiest way. The reason your search results suggested viewing the source was that usually when people want to save SWF files, they are taking them out of existing web pages. By contrast, you are looking directly at the SWF file - you don't have to try to find the url in a web page's source because you're already at that url.

Comment: Upon further research, there actually are ways to "convert" images to SWF files. But that's not really what you're looking for anyway.

Comment: I spoke carelessly; in Firefox and Chrome, there's just the one menu, and saving options are in there. Internet Explorer does have a file menu, but it's hidden by default.

Comment: oh ok, I just saw it. Thanks!